# Syntax error wile trying out NRQL in NewRelic

Tags: python, graphql, newrelic

I am trying to fetch some data via NewRelic's NerdGraph GraphQL API.

```
url="https://api.newrelic.com/graphql"
headers={"API-Key": api_key}

nrql="""{
            actor {
                account(id: 1234) {
                    name
                    }
                }
        }
"""
response=requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, json={'query': nrql})
```

However, I am getting an error.

`{'errors': [{'locations': [{'column': 2, 'line': 1}], 'message': 'syntax error before: "\\"query\\""'}]}`

The same query works in NerdGraph API Explorer application in New Relic. What could be wrong here?

Comment: You need to be making a POST requests not a GET request

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using requests.get, instead of requests.post.

Changed it to post and it worked.